# How to get react-router v4 "staticContext" working with async routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, code-splitting

After I implementing async routes (I use [loadable-components](https://github.com/smooth-code/loadable-components)) with my react SSR project. I found the `staticContext` won't work. If I use static route component instead of async component the `staticContext` works as expectation. Any suggestion for it?

Here's my `NotFound` page:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';

import styles from './styles.scss';

type Props = { staticContext: Object };

export default ({ staticContext }: Props) => {
  // I assing the 404 status here
  if (staticContext) staticContext.status = '404';

  return (
    <div className={styles.NotFound}>
      <Helmet title="Oops" />
      <p>Oops, Page was not found!</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Then I check the status from my `server.js`:

```js
...

const staticContext = {};
      const AppComponent = (
        <Provider store={store}>
          {/* Setup React-Router server-side rendering */}
          <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={staticContext}>
            {renderRoutes(routes)}
          </StaticRouter>
        </Provider>
      );

      if (staticContext.url) {
        res.status(301).setHeader('Location', staticContext.url);
        res.end();

        return;
      }

      // Extract loadable state from application tree (loadable-components setup)
      getLoadableState(AppComponent).then(loadableState => {
        const head = Helmet.renderStatic();
        const assets = webpackIsomorphicTools.assets();
        const htmlContent = renderToString(AppComponent);
        const initialState = store.getState();
        const loadableStateTag = loadableState.getScriptTag();

        // I can't get the "404" error 
        const status = staticContext.status === '404' ? 404 : 200;

...
```

react: 16.2.0
react-router: 4.2.2
node: 9.5.0